# what are the Dependencies that i need to use junit 5 and junit 4?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit4, junit5

since i am new at Junit 5 and i read that they are seperate the jars now in Junit 5, so what i need to attach?

i was looking at the maven repository and i found there much dependencies for junit 5 and i do not know what i should include for runing Junit 4 tests in Junit 5, and what is seperatly for Junit 5 alone?

i have no code yet but needs only the dependencies to understand what i 
need to download

also what the surefire does for all of these?

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
            </dependency>
```

update - so surefire is for search for the missing dependencies,
what are does for?

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.0-M1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0-M1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0-M1</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
         <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
          <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: *I have no code yet* then why worrying about junit4 in junit5?

Comment: haha...right @Lino

Comment: no code using junit5 @Lino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question:** what the surefire does for all of these?

If in POM.xml your dependencies are not well mentioned then Surefire detects which JUnit version to use.

Surefire supports 3 different generations of JUnit: **JUnit 3.8.x**, **JUnit 4.x** (serial provider) and **JUnit 4.7** (junit-core provider with parallel support)

**The algorithm works something like this:**

```
if the JUnit 5 Platform Engine is present in the project
    use junit-platform
if the JUnit version in the project >= 4.7 and the <<<parallel>>> configuration parameter has ANY value
    use junit47 provider
if JUnit >= 4.0 is present
    use junit4 provider
else
    use junit3.8.1
```

**Edit**: *Dependencies required for Junit 5:* [ref1](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#dependency-metadata) , [ref2](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

[Reference](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html)

Comment: so junit5 is not supported with these version detect?
and about the dependencies what i need to attach?

Comment: what is the params dependency?
and these is just for the runing junit 5, what about 4 in 5?